# How to parse JSON in Windows Store / Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

The url that I have returns follwing JSON

```
[{"Id":21,"Name":"Pop","Description":"Pop Music"},{"Id":22,"Name":"Classical","Description":"Classical Music"},{"Id":23,"Name":"Rock","Description":"Rock Music"}]
```

and I want to populate `List<Genre> genreList;`
where Genre looks like

```
class Genre
{
  int Id{get;set;}
  string Pop{get;Set;}
  string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I wrote following code but it is not at all working

```
public List<Genre> GetAllGenres()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response =  client.G(new Uri("http://localhost/MusicAPI/api/Genre/GetAllGenres/"));
            var jsonString =  response.Content.ReadAsString();

            List<Genre> list = await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Genre[]>(jsonString);
            return list;
        }
```

Please suggest..

Here is the answer given by Jagath

```
 public GenreItemViewer()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            GetResponse();
        }

        public async void GetResponse()
        {
            var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/MusicAPI/api/Genre/GetAllGenres/");
            postRequest.Method = "GET";
            postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); ;

            HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            string response = String.Empty;
            if (postResponse != null)
            {
                var postResponseStream = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
                var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

                response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            List<Genre> list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genre>>(response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
List<Genre> list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genre>>(jsonString);
```

For Getting the Http response

```
var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);               
postRequest.Method = "GET";                
postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();;

HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();

if (postResponse != null)
{
   var postResponseStream = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
   var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

   string response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    return response;// This is the response
}
```

Comment: This sections is also wrong in the above code                        var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response =  client.G(new Uri("http://localhost/MusicAPI/api/Genre/GetAllGenres/"));
            var jsonString =  response.Content.ReadAsString();

Comment: yes the method I wrote GetAllGenres() is completely wrong , it just wrote a overview how a method should looks

Comment: I am not getting the right code to send http request to get http response in JSOn

Comment: Thanks, I am testing this Code

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft json nuget package where you can do that parsing using one line of code.

```
List<Genre> genList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genre>>(e.Result);
```

in which e.result contains your response json. follow [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  string jsonstring = await client.GetStringAsync(webaddress);
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);`

After getting the parsed string you can store or use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the list of genre class object

```
List<Genre> genreList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genre>>(jsonString.Result.ToString());
```

**PS** : When u give **jsonString** instead of **jsonString.Result.ToString()** as data for deserializing, You will get Null reference Exception